QGIS regular expression doesn't work for '
I have the atttribute table with the values like these:
'WOLF CLOSE'
'ROBERTSON WAY'
'JEFFREY DRIVE'
and so forth...
I would like to get rid of the ', although the regular formula for the replace seems not to work
 regexp_replace("STREET",''','')

Is there any other way to get rid of the apostrophe mark?

you'll need to escape the middle ' - I forget what the escape char is for those expressions try \\'

Why use regexp_replace rather than a simple replace ? anyway in both case you will need to escape the quote by doubling it so use regexp_replace("STREET",'''','') or replace("STREET",'''','')

Also note that unless you use a more complex expression in your regex_replace this will also remove legitimate quote if present (ie. it will turn 'O'Hare International Airport' to  OHare International Airport)

Use this: replace (STREET, '''','')

Variant: to remove only single quotes ' at the start and end and keep them inside the string (O'Hare International Airport, see comment by @J.R), use:
 regexp_replace (STREET,'^''|''$','')
'O'Hare International Airport' ->  O'Hare International Airport
In RegEx, ^ stands for start, $ for end of line, see here. The pipe | is a logical OR operator.
